# Avoiding sub2ind and ind2sub

Tags: matlab, indexing, computer-vision, bsxfun

I need to access several indices around a certain point in 3D.
For example, for point (`x1`,`y1`,`z1`) I need to get all the indices of its 3x3x3 neighborhood such that (`x1`,`y1`,`z1`) is centered. For neighborhood of size 3, I do it with

```
 [x,y,z] = meshgrid(-1:1,-1:1,-1:1);
 x_neighbors = bsxfun(@plus,x,x1);
 y_neighbors = bsxfun(@plus,y,y1);
 z_neighbors = bsxfun(@plus,z,z1);
```

Here, I center `x1`,`y1`,`z1` to (0,0,0) by adding the distances from (`x1`,`y1`,`z1`) to any point in the 3x3x3 box.

that gives me the coordinates of (`x1`,`y1`,`z1`) 3x3x3 neighborhood. I then need to turn them into linear indices so I can access them:

```
 lin_ind = sub2ind(size(volume),y_neighbors,x_neighbors,z_neighbors);
```

that is costly in what I do.

My question is, how to avoid `sub2ind`. If `inx` is the linear index of (`x1`,`y1`,`z1`),

```
inx = sub2ind(size(volume),y1,x1,z1);
```

how can I find the 3x3x3 neighborhood of the linear index by adding or subtracting or any other simple operation of `inx`?

Comment: Why do you need linear indexes? What operations are you doing with this? Can't you just get the neighbourhood like `M(x_neighbors, y_neighbors, z_neighbors)`? Also you could just do this instead of meshgrid etc: `M(x_neighbors-1:x_neighbors+1, y_neighbors-1:y_neighbors+...etc`

Comment: You can always do the `array(i + rows*j + rows*cols*k)`-type of calculation yourself... Just look at how `sub2ind` does it and copy-paste the relevant parts.

Comment: @Dan, Can't access M(y_n,x_n,z_n) Because I need just part of the 3x3x3 neighborhood, (I apply a mask on the indices) so what I actually have is x_list, y_list,z_list and accessing M(y_list,x_list,z_list) gives all position with y_list,x_list,z_list, and not their combinations.... I can't use your other suggestion because I have many points (p1,...pn) and not just one (x1,y1,z1), and I need to do it fast..

Comment: Since x1, y1, z1 are scalars, you don't have to use bsxfun. `x_neighbors = x + x1` works too.

Comment: @Alex They are not scalars, just in this example they are... they are actually huge array, I mentioned it earlier in my response to Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you know the dimensions of your 3D array, you can compute the linear offsets of all the elements of the 3x3x3 neighborhood.  To illustrate this, consider a 2D example of a 4x5 matrix.  The linear indices look like this:

```
1 5  9 13 17
2 6 10 14 18
3 7 11 15 19
4 8 12 16 20
```

The 3x3 neighborhood of 10 is `[5 6 7 9 10 11 13 14 15]`.  The 3x3 neighborhood of 15 is `[10 11 12 14 15 16 18 19 20]`.  If we subtract off the index of the central element, in both cases we get `[-5 -4 -3 -1 0 1 3 4 5]`.  More generally, for `M`x`N` matrix we will have `[-M-1 -M -M+1 -1 0 1 M-1 M M+1]`, or `[(-M+[-1 0 1]) -1 0 1 (M+[-1 0 1])]`.

Generalizing to three dimensions, if the array is `M`x`N`x`P`, the linear index offsets from the central element will be `[(-M*N+[-M-1 -M -M+1 -1 0 1 M-1 M M+1]) [-M-1 -M -M+1 -1 0 1 M-1 M M+1] (M*N+[-M-1 -M -M+1 -1 0 1 M-1 M M+1])]`.  You can reshape this to 3x3x3 if you wish.

Note that this sort of indexing doesn't deal well with edges; if you want to find the neighbors of an element on the edge of the array you should probably pad the array on all sides first (thereby changing `M`, `N`, and `P`).

Comment: Thank you!! this is exactly what I wanted. I just needed to generalize it one bit more, for larger neighborhood (and not only 3X3), so taking what you did, the series should go up to floor(neighborhood_size/2), for example, for 5X5: floor(5/2) = 2, I'l have: [-M-2 -M-1 M -M+1 -M+2 -2 -1 0 ....] (same with positives). Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Just adding the (generalized) code to @nhowe answer:
This is an example for neighborhood of size 5X5X5, therefore r (the radius) is 2:

```
ns = 5;
r = 2;

[M,N,D] = size(vol);
rs = (1:ns)-(r+1);
% 2d generic coordinates:
neigh2d = bsxfun(@plus, M*rs,rs');
% 3d generic coordinates:
pages = (M*N)*rs;
pages = reshape(pages,1,1,length(pages));

neigh3d = bsxfun(@plus,neigh2d,pages);
```

to get any neighborhood of any linear index of vol, just add the linear index to neigh3d:

```
new_neigh = bxsfun(@plus,neigh3d, lin_index);
```

Comment: I know this is an old question, but from `neigh2d`, how do I access the value of the matrix since the coordinate in `neigh2d`  consists negative value? I'm only consider 2D matrix.