# Fast general replacements for ind2sub and sub2ind MATLAB

Tags: matlab, indexing

Strangely enough I could not find a general answer for this simple question. The one linked answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144291/avoiding-sub2ind-ind2sub-matlab) is *not* general.

`sub2ind` can be avoided, I believe, with the following equivalence [[here](http://tipstrickshowtos.blogspot.com/2010/02/fast-replacement-for-sub2ind.html)]

`sub2ind(size(A), row1, row2, row3, row4)` is equivalent to 
    `row1+ (row2-1)*size(A,1) + (row3-1)*size(A,1) *size(A,2) + (row4-1)*size(A,1) *size(A,2) *size(A,3)`.

Meanwhile `ind2sub` for 2 dimensions (i.e., no `row3, row4`....) can be avoided as:

```
i = rem(index-1,size(A,1))+1;
j = (index-i)/size(A,1)+ 1 ;
```

is equivalent to:

```
[i,j] = ind2sub(size(A),index);
```

How do we generalize `ind2sub` for 3D matrices and so on? I am not interested in debates about whether we should avoid it or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ind2sub` code can be generalized simply by adding another `rem` over the second dimension:

```matlab
i = rem(index-1, size(A,1)) + 1;
index = (index-i) / size(A,1) + 1;
j = rem(index-1, size(A,2)) + 1;
k = (index-j) / size(A,2) + 1;
```

This is actually a lot easier to do using zero-based indexing, since it gets rid of all the `+1` and `-1` bits. This would be the generalized code for any number of dimensions:

```matlab
index = index-1; % convert to 0-based indexing
sz = size(A);
i = zeros(size(sz));
for d = 1:numel(sz)
   i(d) = rem(index, sz(d));
   index = (index - i(d)) / sz(d);
end
i = i + 1; % convert back to 1-based indexing
```

Comment: Cris Luengo, congrats your first post to my questions without criticism ;) Mind explaining your code a bit especially the second half?

Comment: @bissi, congrats on your first question that doesn't need improving! :p

Comment: @bissi: The code in the second half does exactly what your 2D code does, but in a loop. Your `j` is the linear index into dimensions 2, 3, etc. (basically, you've separated out the index along dimension 1, `j` is the remainder). You can now repeat the same process by mentally removing the first dimension from your array, and use the same calculation to separate out the index along dimension 2. This process you can repeat for each remaining dimension.

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote

```
i = rem(index-1, size(A,1)) + 1;
index = (index-i) / size(A,1) + 1;
j = rem(index-1, size(A,2)) + 1;
k = (index-i) / size(A,2) + 1;
```

This part over here doesn't seem to work properly with the k. I see different values for the ind2sub's obtained k and the one obtained in the given code. (diff is smaller than 1 though)

EDIT: seems that last line needs to be

> Blockquote

`k = (index-j) / size(A,2) + 1;`

Finally, checking with "tic/toc", this implementation is not faster that ind2sub in Matlab R2020b...

Comment: I think in the last like it should be
k = (index-*j*) / size(A,2) + 1;

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed the code in my post.